# Unable to create a Wordpress multisite network for an existing installation, A Last Hope

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, permalinks, multisite

I have a website with some large number of posts like (75k posts).

Till now, i am using a plugin called Main Category As Sub-domain to convert categories into sub-domains.

ISSUE - 1 → In recent wordpress 4.7 update, few functions of that plugins are depreciated. I don't think that plugin's author is going update it.

ISSUE - 2 → I tried to use its alternative plugins, but they are having some permalink restrictions which are causing 404 errors for my existing posts. So, i cant use them.

My current permalink structure is /%post_id%/%postname%/

After all, I decided to convert my single WP into Multisite.

I followed all steps in http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

But after changing .htaccess and wp-config.php, I logged out.

ISSUE - 3 →When i login again, i am not seeing anything new in WP Dashboard. (i.e) Network is not setup. I tried it many times but no use.

I am not able to understand what is causing this issue.

ISSUE - 4 → Also, i tried to create an alternative WP multisite to export all category posts to specific sub-sites. I know this will work but taking long time to process exporting and importing as i can only export 2000-2500 posts at once.

MY IDEAS

1. Using .htaccess rules to redirect 404 errors when using alternative
   plugins.
2. Importing and Exporting posts with help of MySQL.

I don't know whether these are possible or not. But

- Please help me, setup a network for my site.
- Or provide any alternative idea.
- Any kind of response would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php make define('WP_DEBUG', true);. It will show you what and where the problem is.